# Using SOS, it possible to merge all files in a branch to the trunk in one operation?

Tags: version-control, sos

Is there any way to tell SOS to merge all the latest files in a given branch into the trunk?

I've checked out all the files that are going to change.  I can merge single files by selecting the latest branch revision and using the Revision->Merge menu command. However, the option is greyed out if I select more than one file.  I've quite a few files to merge, and I don't want to do this by hand if at all possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Each file must be merged individually.